# Recent Windows Workflow examples for web application

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation-4, microsoft-dynamics

We will be building (extending) an existing ordering capability on our flagship product.

Currently the ordering functionality only starts a manual fulfillment process via a Sales Force CRM ticket.

The future state is to have the order process and fulfillment process all automated.  This is vehicle acquisition for leasing, so the process will be quite complicated taking into account registration, insurance and driver info on a per state basis.

This is screaming workflow.  I've been reading on WF but I haven't found a lot of current examples.

The tech showed up around 2006 but doesn't seem to have been adopted regularly.

I am looking for some references to implementing WF in a production web application that will integrate with several other systems and individuals to complete the process.

If not WF, is there something else?  We really do not want to implement a bunch of custom rules that will likely change over time.

Comment: I've done this a few times.  As a way forward in your thinking, the easy way to do this is to decouple the workflow from your web app.  Build the workflow as a Windows service  or Azure job and let your web app control it via queue, WCF or REST messages.

Comment: That is basically the architecture we have in place now.  The web app surfaces an Angular site, but all of logic exists on windows services deployed to a different server.  So put the workflow in the service and just invoke the various methods through the web app (or other external systems).

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly then that's not quite what I do.  I put the windows workflow in the service and get the web app to invoke and continue it.  That way the workflow controls the execution path.  The workflow then invokes the methods rather than the web app invoking the methods directly.